# Google Cloud Sql - suddenly changed its IP, turned off Backup and all my data are lost. (old status automatically restored)

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, backup, google-cloud-sql

I've been using Google Cloud Sql for one year like a charm but some days ago something bad (and very serious) happened: the database, automatically, changed its IP address and restored an old status (related to a snapshot of 8-9 months ago) without informing me or asking me for a prompt.
I've just noticed it because i wasn't able to connect to DB.

All the backups are gone (I don't know why... It was set to "automatic backup" and now it's off. I don't know what do to to restore my data).

Does anyone of you have had similar issues? 
Do you know what can I do to get in touch with Google? 
Because I didn't do anything, but all the data, as if by magic , are gone...

All I can see are these screens:

[image: Details]

[image: operations log]

Comment: To file a support ticket: In your GCP Console go to Navigation Menu (upper left corner) --> Support --> Cases

Comment: they say I can contact them only with a "premium" account

Comment: You can also try the Chat (just below the Cases) and see if it works. Another thing, you may file the issue here --> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0

Comment: thank you Christopher, it's nice of you!